# Consolidaing financial models (excel files) by python

Tags: python

Suppose I have 6 financials models of three companies (AQ1, AQ2, BQ1, BQ2, CQ1 and CQ2 ... all excel files s.) These models have many line items (Revenue, EBITDA, Interet Expense, Aseets, etc.) I want only three line items (Revenue, EBITDA and Net Income) in a consolidating file. How can I do it in python? We were using VBA for this and the code is not working. I want to do this in python as in reality there are 100s of models. Can you please suggest an easy and efficient python flow ?

I am looking for something like:

Q stands for Quarter

AQ1 Revenue : 530 /n
AQ1 EBITDA : 400 / n
AQ1 Net Income : 100 /n

AQ2 Revenue :
AQ2 EBITDA: 
...

BQ1 Revenue : 456
BQ1 EBITDA : 309
BQ1 Net Income : 108

...

Comment: We need more information about the data. Also without showing any of your own effort most people, including me, won't be very willing to help. Try looking over the StackOverflow "How to ask a good question" guidelines page ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ).

Comment: It is a complex problem and should be split into parts: how to read an Excel file in Python? How to cycle over its lines and get only desired ones? etc.

Comment: I will try this one and come back .. http://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html

Comment: VBA guys are so confident about this problem.. I think python is evolving and people hesitate to suggest bold answers ..